# Overcoming Javascript Floating point issues

Tags: javascript

```
parseInt(1.164 * 100000) === 116399
```

I know that the max number of decimal places is 5. Is there a way to make sure to remove all rounding errors?

EDIT: I am getting a few down votes so I wanted to clarify the issue a bit more

1. I know the max decimal is 5 because I know that it is not possible for the database to return a float with more than 5 decimal places
2. There are no strings involved. It is a float.
3. I don't want to use a precision library because it is too heavy to include a library to fix a small bug for the front end.
4. I am wondering if I use Math.round and I will still have issues. For instance, the bug here is 1.164 becomes 1.16399999 (so I can fix the issue by rounding up) but is it possible for 1.164 become 1.6400000001. In this case, if I round up, round it to 116401.

Comment: Where did you get the idea "that the max number of decimal places is 5?" 15 is much more common. For example, in Chrome, `1.23456789012345 + 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230 = 4.376160543713243`.

Comment: You need to use parseFloat to get precision

Comment: Also, this is much too broad a question. There are precise-math libraries out there, but as phrased, this question is too broad to get a good answer here.

Comment: The OP is not an example of a "rounding error", it shows the lack of precision of IEEE 754 floating point values.

Comment: @self: No! There are no strings involved, so there is no need to parse anything.

Comment: @Bergi You are right. I was assuming he was using strings not based on his provided line

Comment: @EdCottrell I know the max decimal is 5 because I know that it is not possible for the database to return a float with more than 5 decimal places.

Comment: @EdCottrell how can I make the question more precise? There are no strings involved. It is a float. I don't want to use a precision library because it is too heavy to include a library for the front end. I am wondering if I use Math.round and I will still have issues. For instance can 1.164 become 1.6400000001 which if I round up, round it to 116401

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What are those numbers and why are you comparing them?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.round()`:

```
Math.round(1.164 * 100000)
```

It will give you `116400`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways to make sure to remove all "rounding errors".

1. Use a different language.
2. As a commenter mentioned, use a fixed-point or high-precision library.
3. Use a new (non-existent) implementation of JS which represents numbers in a different way, such as Crockford's "DEC64" proposal; see https://github.com/douglascrockford/DEC64/.